# Подключение модуля JavaScript лишь на отдельной странице

Tags: javascript, модули

Итак, вопрос в следующем:
есть две страницы, index и single-page, используется шаблонизатор, на страницах меняется лишь контентная часть, шапка у всех общая, в ней подключается файл main.js, доступный на всех страницах.

На второй странице (single-page) есть табы с данными, работа табов реализована через JavaScript, код я вынес в отдельный модуль - Tabs.js. Соответственно, main.js
содержит в себе импорт данного модуля:

```
// main.js
import Tabs from "./js/modules/Tabs.js"; 
Tabs();
```

По сути, этот код нужен лишь для страницы single-page, а на index он не используется, так как там табов нет, но вызывается main.js везде. И я хочу понять, как правильно реализовывать работу такого модуля лишь в нужной ситуации. Должен ли он содержать в себе какие-то проверки на адрес страницы, или проверки селекторов табов указывающих на то, что выборка успешна и такой-то элемент есть и с ним можно работать, или что-то еще?

Comment: сделайте проверку, если нет табов, то `return` и скрипт не будет работать

Comment: @meine да, я в таком духе и сделал, просто у меня main.js получается как такой набор вызовов разных модулей-функций, вида: tabs() - проверяет на табы, modals() - содержит логику модалок, функция addToWatchlist() - вообще отвечает за работу кнопки добавления фильма в список, она тоже для отдельной страницы нужна. И получается такой вот разнородный список вызовов модулей-функций, рождающих ощущение, что что-то не так. Я и решил узнать, может есть какие-то способы для структурирования этого всего.

Comment: есть 1 метод, но он очень хитрый)

Comment: @meine ну, для расширения кругозора приведите, если не сложно) Но я в целом просто хотел узнать, вышеописанный мною/вами подход он вообще так в разработке и применяется, я не реализую какой-то велосипедный костыль при использовании описанной выше структуры кода?

Comment: А если заинлайнить этот скрипт именно на ту сктраницу на которую надо? А импорт из `main` убрать

Comment: Метод, который вы/я привёл используется, ничего страшного и костыльного в этом нет

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов тоже можно конечно, просто у меня про инлайн за время обучения сформировалось мнение (возможно превратное) как о чем-то, что допустимо использовать лишь для вставки критически важных для страницы участков кода, выполняющихся как можно быстрее. А все прочее дескать нужно уносить в модули/внешние ресурсы.

Comment: @meine хорошо, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Tabs {
  constructor(node) {
    if (!node) return;
    
    // if node does not exist on the current page, the script would be disable
    
    console.log('Tabs does exist on the current page.')
  }
}

new Tabs(document.querySelector('.tabs'));
```

```html
<div class="tabs"></div>
```

Comment: поздравляю с 6000 - круглая 'дата'

Comment: @MaximLensky, спасибо)